# Are multi-qubit control RX gates scaling exponentially?

Tags: quantum-gate, resource-request

In https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0303063.pdf it a method shown for implementing a multi-qubit controlled phase shift gate thath scales exponentially with n.

Are there new methods to implement these gates in polynomial time?

And does anybody know if there is a paper descring the method for impelemnting a multi-qubit controlled gate that Qiskit uses for its MCMT gate?
https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.MCMT.html

Comment: The classic source for that is [Barenco et al., Elementary gates for quantum computation](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An $n$-qubit controlled phase gate with error $\epsilon$ takes $O(n + \lg \frac{1}{\epsilon})$ gates to achieve.

The $O(n)$ dependence is easiest to understand in the case where you have $n$ ancillae:

[image: construction]

The $O(\lg \frac{1}{\epsilon})$ dependence is from the need to decompose the single qubit phase rotation into the gateset that is actually supported, e.g. using [repeat-until-success circuits](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1074).

Only a [single ancilla is actually required](https://algassert.com/circuits/2015/06/05/Constructing-Large-Controlled-Nots.html). And if you're willing to increase the cost to $O(n \cdot \lg \frac{1}{\epsilon})$ and use $n$ arbitrary single qubit phase rotations instead of one [then no ancillae are needed at all](https://algassert.com/circuits/2015/06/22/Using-Quantum-Gates-instead-of-Ancilla-Bits.html).